# How can I access Heroku ClearDB in my Java web application?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have done add-on Heroku of ClearDB and I want to access that database using Hibernate in my Java web application..

I have added the connection  to MySQL workbench too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following properties into your **hibernate.cfg.xml** file.

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://us-cdbr-iron-east-03.cleardb.net:3306/heroku_123456789?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">my_username</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">my_passsword</property>
```

Please note that the property value of the **hibernate.connection.url** is a sample only. But it has the URL format. You have replace it with your own URL.

Property values of **hibernate.connection.username** and **hibernate.connection.password** should also be replace.

Comment: yeah..I tried it and it showing me error saying "cannot open connection"

Comment: Are you accessing it through a proxy?

Comment: no..I just run it on localhost using that heroku credentials.